# How to add product to cart in all storeviews?

Tags: cart, multistore, store-view

I'm using this code:

I want to add a product to every cart. When I run the code below I always get the output: `The stock item for Product is not valid.`

I know it somehow has to do with the way I change the stores. Because if I don't change stores, the code works fine.

```
include_once('../app/Mage.php');
ob_start();
umask(0);
Mage::app();

    $stores = array_keys(Mage::app()->getStores());
        foreach($stores as $storeId){
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
            Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId);
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 
            try{
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $v[0]);
                $v[0] = $product->getId(); // fix for Mage problem with stock load id then add
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($v[0]);
                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
                $cart->init();
                $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $v[1]));
                $cart->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $eReturn = $e;
                $returnJson['success']  = false;
                $returnJson['error']    = $eReturn;
                echo $eReturn;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a product to the cart in multiple store views.
I mean, you can but that's useless. The cart is not store view dependent. It's website dependent.
When you add a product to the cart in one store view it is added for all store views under the same website.
When you add the product for the second store view under the same website, you are practically increasing the qty for the quote that corresponds to the website.
That's why you end up with a qty issue.
You should try to add the product to the cart for one store view under each website.

So instead of looping through `$stores = array_keys(Mage::app()->getStores());` you can loop through `$websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();`.
And for each website get any store view assigned to it.